# VIM - Detect Whether a Plugin is Active/Running/Open?

Tags: vim, keyboard-shortcuts, vimrc, vim-plugins

I would like to do some tricks with VIM and so I ask the help of you guys!

- It is possible to detect whether a plugin is active/running/open?
- You can close a plugin by its name?
- You can close a plugin when it loses focus?

The goal is to create keyboard shortcuts (conditional) to be configured in "vimrc" so I can easily switch between plugins!

**Plus!**

Is there any plugin that facilitates the activities mentioned?

**Below is an example:**

I put up an example of some of the things I like to do. In this case, I put a shortcut to the keyboard (in vimrc) that lets you perform a certain action depending on the state of particular plugin. Ie, if the "Dbg" plugin is open, it closes the plugin, if is closed, performs some action before and opens the plugin.

```
"Note: Open or close "VIM Debug" depending on whether it is opened or closed! By Questor
function! ToggleDbg()
        if exists("g:Dbg")
                Dbg quit
                unlet g:Dbg
        else    
                try     
                        "HYPOTHETICAL EXAMPLE ->
                        if isrunning("FOO_PLUGIN")
                            quit("FOO_PLUGIN")
                            "... or do something else...
                        endif
                        "<- HYPOTHETICAL EXAMPLE
                        Dbg .
                        let g:Dbg = 1
                catch   
                        echo "No Errors found!"
                endtry  
        endif   
endfunction
nmap <script><silent><C-F5> :call ToggleDbg()<CR>
```

Comment: This question shows pretty much zero understanding of how plugins work in Vim. There is almost never any concept of an active/running/open plugin. A plugin is either installed or it isn't.

Comment: Ben, if I knew how Vim works I would not have asked here. If you have nothing constructive to say about what I'm asking is better not to say anything. You merely criticize and so marked your comment as constructive and offensive (I'm not stupid, I'm just seeking help).

Comment: I'm sure @Ben didn't mean to personally attack you. He merely mentioned how it really works. Perhaps it would have been better to give a complete answer to the question though.

Comment: Ben, please tell me what I can do to you remove the negatives since I can not delete the question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A plugin isn't running "in the background"; its effect is by defining custom mappings / commands / event handlers.

To check for those, you can use the `exists()` and `hasmapto()` functions.

#### Warning

"Do some tricks" is a vague and dangerous motivation. In general, plugins can easily co-exist; just choose distinct mappings. Some plugins (*AsNeeded*) and package managers (*VAM*) allow to "lazily" load plugins (on first use), but that just helps with reducing the startup time (which, with well-written plugins using the autoload feature shouldn't matter, anyway).

Please give more background; what is your final goal? When a question is only about a small technical step, it's difficult to provide a good answer. If you don't tell us **why** you want this, it's easy to succumb to the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Ingo, I put additional information about what you asked. Note also that "exists("g:Dbg")" does not check whether a plugin is running or not, it depends on "let g:Dbg = 1". Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for adding that information; your question is in much better shape now! You're right that checking for the include guard variable is also viable, though I would prefer to check for an actual mapping / command, as it's more robust.

Comment: I try what you told me and give you a feedback! Thanks!